Java process cannot set GroupID when running in Supervisor
I am running a java process that sets OWNER/GROUP of files.   Found that it throws "Operation Not Permitted" Exception when I run it under Supervisor.      Strange issue, is that it only does this for 1 of 10 different groups AND if I do it from the command line using same account that supervisor is using it works.
Any Ideas would be welcomed.
Recycled Supervisor.
Forced LINUX to reload groups.

You would have better chance of answers if you put in the code that fails with exception details

One possible reason for this behavior is that Supervisor may not have the necessary permissions to set the group ID for the java process. When running from the command line, the user may have certain permissions that Supervisor does not have.
To troubleshoot this issue, you can try the following steps:

Check the permissions and ownership of the files and directories involved. Ensure that Supervisor has the necessary permissions to modify the group ID of the files.

Verify that the user account used by Supervisor has the appropriate group membership to be able to set the group ID.

Check if there are any specific configurations or restrictions in Supervisor that may be preventing the group ID from being set.

Review the logs or error messages generated by Supervisor when the exception occurs to see if there are any clues about the specific reason for the "Operation Not Permitted" error.

Consider running the java process with elevated privileges (e.g., using sudo) to see if the issue is related to permissions.


By following these steps, you may be able to identify and resolve the underlying cause of the issue with setting the group ID when running the java process in Supervisor.
